# How to query extra field in many to many relationship of typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I have a user entity like this

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @OneToMany(() => UserLikePost, (userLikePost) => userLikePost.post)
  likedPosts: UserLikePost[];
}
```

and post entity like this

```
@Entity()
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.likedPosts)
  likedUsers: User[];
}
```

and bridge entity like this

```
@Entity()
export class UserLikePost extends BaseEntity {
  static random() {}

  @Column({
    type: 'boolean',
  })
  isLike: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.likedPosts)
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.likedUsers)
  post: Post;
}
```

So basically I have a bridge entity between user and post that stores isLike column that decides if a user has like the post or not.

the list query works fine for example I can do

```
postRepository.find({
  relation: ['likedUsers']
})
```

and I get list of corresponding UserLikePosts.

However, what I would really like to do is to get a list of posts in whatever order and add a boolean field to each post showing whether a specific user has liked the post or not.

Now I could just load all UserLikePost rows and filter the whether the user exists in the list but it seems like a huge waste of memory. I would like the query to be run in the DB and return only the boolean result whether the liked user exists in the UserLikePost table for target post.

How do I perform this query using typeorm?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get all posts that specific user liked, you can use nested where, i.e.

```
userLikePostRepository.find({
   where: {
     isLike: true,
     user: {
       id: <userId>,
     },
   },
   relation: ['post']
})
```

Comment: yes I know but I am trying to list the posts from 1 index to 20 and if I want to figure out if a user has liked each of the posts between index 1 - 20 in one query, what do I do?